# Reloading page when fetching new tab item in bootstrap card

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code in javascript that allows me to visit a page with a hashbang on it to visit a tab

```
// Javascript to enable link to tab
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})
```

This is an example link `http://localhost/centosapp/info/configure#description`

I am showing a tab on click using

```
$('#bologna-list a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
});
```

this is the html

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" id="bologna-list" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="<?php echo base_url('info/configure'); ?>#description" role="link" aria-controls="description" aria-selected="true">Devices</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link"  href="<?php echo base_url('info/configure'); ?>#history" role="link" aria-controls="history" aria-selected="false">Add Asset</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('info/configure'); ?>#deals" role="link" aria-controls="deals" aria-selected="false">My Assets</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">          
           <div class="tab-content mt-3">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="description" role="tabpanel">
            ...items are shown here
        </div>
        </div>
```

I want to be able to reload page so that to get new content from server when i click on a tab.How can i reload and show the tab clicked on bootstrap?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `e.preventDefault()`? Seems to me that you already have the rest of the process set up. Edit: Add window.location.reload() to reload.

Comment: Nope, thats not it. The way i used to do it is by having each click handler handle a tab of its own. I have too many tabs now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it this way using a html `data-*` tag.

```
<div class="card-header">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" id="bologna-list" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#description" data-link="http://localhost/centosapp/info/configure#description"  role="link" aria-controls="description" aria-selected="true">Devices</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link"  href="#history" data-link="http://localhost/centosapp/info/configure#history"  role="link" aria-controls="history" aria-selected="false">Add Asset</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#deals" data-link="http://localhost/centosapp/info/configure#deals" role="link" aria-controls="deals" aria-selected="false">My Assets</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

and js

```
$('#bologna-list a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show');
  var links = $(this).attr("data-link");
  window.location.href = links;
});
```

Works but a solution inside bootstrap would have worked better.